# Copy data from one data base to another database

Tags: sql

I have tow database server
Server: a , Database name: FMIS , table name: employee
Server: b, Database name : KPS, table name: employee.
I need a SQL command which which will copy data from employee table of FMIS to employee table of KPS.
I have written a formula like below, but its not working.

insert into a.fmis.employee(Column1, Column2,...)
select Column1, Column2,...
from b.kps.employee

what will be the correct SQL command?

Answer (score 0):

If they were on the same server then it would be easy to copy from one database to the other, but since they aren't you'll need to transfer it somewhat manually.

You should be able to use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
```

to get the table structure, and

```
SELECT * FROM tablename INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/save.tsv'
```

(make sure the file does NOT exist and the user has FILES permissions) to export the data.

Then copy this information to the other server.

You can just run the `CREATE TABLE` you got from the first step, and then use

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/save.tsv' INTO TABLE tablename
```

to import the data. Note that the target table name need not be the same as the original.

Comment: I have run this like SELECT * FROM name INTO OUTFILE 'C:/save.tsv' but showing incorrect syntax near into. Can you please help?

Comment: There should be no space in `OUTFILE` or `INFILE` - they are single keywords.

Comment: yes I did not put any space. like  SELECT * FROM name INTO OUTFILE 'C:/save.tsv'

Comment: Did you put in your table name there? What implementation of SQL are you using anyway? You never specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your server b as a linked server on server a and run your query that you have written. This link might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff772782.aspx